# I'm looking for texts and talks where Zizek talks about Mimetic Theory of Rene Girard

Tags: zizek

I'm looking for texts and talks, where Zizek responds to the Mimetic Theory of Rene Girard. Also the other way around would be interesting.

Comment: Seems unlikely there would be much "Girard-on-Zizek" but I feel like there's some Zizek on Girard in that book he does with the theologian (I believe it's called *God in Pain*?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found some references to these commentaries in [Monica Germana(ed.) e.a., Apocalyptic Discourse in Contemporary Culture: Post-Millennial Perspectives on the End of the World, p. 52, 2014](https://books.google.be/books?id=9B-DBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=zizek+mimetic+theory+ren%C3%A9+girard&source=bl&ots=4B5ZTidkyL&sig=ybJTzReielPd1XZIPGPf7TiTeP0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WbvUVPiELYKyUfexgkg&ved=0CFYQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=zizek%20mimetic%20theory%20ren%C3%A9%20girard&f=false).

Žižek indeed talks about mimicry in "Slavoj Žižek & Boris Gunjevic, God in Pain: Inversion of Acopaclypse, New York: Seven Stories Press, **p. 124-126**, 2012"; where in these passages, the **mimicry** seems related to the **feminine**.

In the same book ([click here](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fm.friendfeed-media.com%2F07ae58439969f69c25f7f9dce96c3d10ae7fa7ca&ei=QzrVVPTPApDVaqD1gZAK&usg=AFQjCNGKTqxrnEgVwtfOqPPFFxyULH7CYw&sig2=9jJxXRKWDxJWnmujZugLaw) to download) on *pages 63-64*: **René Girard** and **scapegoating** are mentioned.

More assumed comments/allusions of Žižek on René Girard can be found in the source linked to above.

Answer (score 4):

There is some discussion of Girard in [this video](https://youtu.be/NEEBYNNpX9o) (discussion with Jean-Pierre Dupuy) around minute 32.

Answer (score 0):

Some Zizek excerpts commenting on Girard (actually, mostly just paraphrasing) can be found here: https://mimeticmargins.com/2017/11/28/slavoj-zizek-on-atheism-christianity/